# Record user action and save it as swf file using flash cs6 + as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

i'm trying to track user action on my flash project and store it as swf file or video any help please 
I write this code that capture bitmaps and show them when click
the movieclip

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,capture)
    var ar=new Array()
    function capture(e:Event)
    {
        trace("done")
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
    bd.draw(stage);
    var screenshot:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
    ar.push(screenshot)
    }
    vv.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gg)
    var xx=0
    var intr
    var interval
    function gg(e:MouseEvent)
    {    
    interval = setInterval(reg_st, 24);


    }
    function reg_st()
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,capture)

        stage.addChild(ar[xx])
        if(xx<ar.length-1)
        {
        xx++
        }
        else
        {
            xx=0
        }
    }
```

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Tracking is simple, add listeners to stange to track keyboard input and mouse inputs, you'll be interested in following:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onUserKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUserKeyUP);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onUserMouseMove);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onUserMouseUp);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUserMouseDown);
```

The handlers will simply put the events in an array with a timestamp when the input occurred.

The harder part is playback. Or actually - the interaction. You will basically need to simulate the whole program. It can be insanely hard, or pretty easy, depending on the structure and logic of your app. I won't be able to provide you with a code for such problem, but I can share a step-by-step logic that might help you make your own solution:

1. Add listeners to all expected user interactions not root level of the program
2. Make a few collectors that will store all the events with timestamps and maybe a pointer of the object.
3. Get the data (send this data on user quitting the program, or entering the program from the previous session)
4. Call the methods (handlers) from the user interaction array with a time offset provided by the timestamp information. NOTE: you'll need to brake encapsulation and make all these methods public.
5. Enjoy your "video".

Comment: Why directly holding the pointers on the object? These are invalidated once the app ends. You have to get metadata on the object that's receiving user input, say if it's a "selectDialog.btnToggleParameter" in source(!), you will have to derive the actual link starting from stage. It will like be in form `stage.getChildAt(0)["selectDialog"]["btnToggleParameter"]`, and you can get these values only if they are public. BUT, another way is possible - `stage.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(7).getChildAt(11)` where the numbers are derivable by querying DisplayList starting from `event.target`.

Comment: Next, you can attempt to capture events as they bubble up (some event don't bubble, so you really have to attach listeners for them on their targets, others reach stage eventually), and then you **dispatch** correct Events providing whole set of parameters for a correct event using `stage.dispatchEvent(...)`, literally simulating user input. With this approach, no encapsulation break is necessary.

Comment: I suppose your method will work perfectly as long as the developer uses the Event model. But if the user uses signals, callbacks etc. I believe the only thing we're left with is adding listeners to input sources and tracking inputs. As I've said earlier it's not hard to reproduce the users actions, as much as interacting with the GUI having only this data.
Well, my answer is more theoretical and might not fit the actual implementation for the planned application design. Therefor I don't claim that my answer is the only best, working or possible one.

Comment: Hmm, do we actually need anything but keyboard and mouse events from the user, and enterframe events from the app? All of these can be captured at stage level, we will need to track focused component for keyboard events, so we can call `setFocus` via captured displaylist position (BTW, if an application is non-deterministic aka uses `Math.random()` to move interactable objects, even this will fail, as we can't intercept `Math.random()` calls) and dispatch the events with discretion. I was just attempting to rectify your general method, not critique it.

Comment: And you did it beautifully. It was really interesting to read it :) I will definitely make this thing myself. It's hard to think of all the details and all the milestones. You actually foresaw much more then I have in my attempt to imagine the workflow of such app.